# What Does 1614234446082ms Mean and How can You Limit It(JDA Java Discord Bot)

Tags: java, discord-jda

I am trying to make a ping-pong bot that will respond with your ping. The problem is that it responds with this:

```
Pong!
1614234538419%d ms
```

Can someone explain what that means please? Also, if you can, is there a way to simplify this?
Here's the code:

```
package Events;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Message;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

public class PingPong extends ListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent e) {
        Message msg = e.getMessage();
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (msg.getContentRaw().equalsIgnoreCase("!ping")) {
            e.getChannel().sendMessage("Pong!").queue();
            e.getChannel().sendMessage(time + "ms").queue();
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()

Comment: It seems as if the class MessageReceiveEvent gives special treatment to the message passed by the type. Try parsing time to string for ex: String.valueOf(time)

Comment: There is an example ping-pong bot here https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA#listening-to-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`System.currentTimeMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) returns amount of milliseconds since the beginning of Unix epoch, that is, midnight of 1.1.1970 UTC. I'm not sure what you aim to do, but if you want to measure time, you need to compute relative difference of two time points, e.g.

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
// do some long computation
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("Computation took " + (end - start) + " ms");
```

If you're looking to return current time, you can use either `LocalDateTime.now()` (without timezone) or `ZonedDateTime.now()` (with time zone). Mind that returns an object - if you want to print some String representation, you can use `DateTimeFormatter` and pass it format that you want to use:

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm").format(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `e.getChannel().sendMessage(time + "ms").queue()` writes the current time in milliseconds since start of the [unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). That specific value [means](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) “Thu Feb 25 2021 06:27:26 GMT+0000”.

You could remove this line. Or use a method to convert the number to a string. I am not a Java programmer but there is some method for that for sure.